# Android, Why browser of mobile cannot play video while browser of computer can play?

Tags: android, video, webview, media-player

In my application I need to load a web page. this page includes a video player. this is my code:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://astroapps.static.appxtream.com/resepi_video.php?mediaId=209375&height=400&width=240");
```

Also I have activated hardware acceleration in manifest file.

```
<activity android:name = ".WebVideoPlayer" android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
```

When I launch application, screen shows a background while it doesn't play when i click it. When I copy/paste above link in browser of computer it displays the video. What is my mistake?

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Maybe its 2 different browsers?

Comment: Thanks Anders, Yes for mobile is its native browser. On PC i'm using chrome browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confused.  Hans and Rocel point out, the video seems to require the Flash player (at least in the browser).  But the movie player source says to use HTML5 when on Android.  So which is it?  Can you get just the video itself, without all the wrapper layers?

**More:**

Is this a bug in the Movideo player?  It *says* it prefers Flash to Android (in which case the above contributors' advice to install Flash would be right on the money), but the array appears to be backward.

```
    var AndroidApplicationAliasResolver = function() {

    // ordering is important!
    // has flash, use first available of flash and android
    // has not flash, android

    var search,
        types = [
            { name:'android',   useHTML5:true },
            { name:'flash',     useHTML5:false }
        ];
    ...
```

**More:**

Okay, I know this much:  When viewed in the browser, there is a `<div>` that holds data about the video player.  This then gets instantiated and played in the following `<script>`.

In the (PC/Mac) web browser, this `<div>` contains the information necessary to specify a Flash video player.

On the Android device, this `<div>` is simply empty.  The code in the video player that is supposed to insert the `<div>` body into the DOM if the enclosing web page doesn't work.

That, in short, is why your video doesn't play.

**How did I learn all this?**

I opened the URL you provided in the Chrome web browser on Android.
Then I followed the instructions to turn on [remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/debugging) and inspected the HTML of the Android version, and compared it to the desktop version.

Comment: Thanks Sparky, because of copyright issue video provider doesn't let us to have direct access to videos.

Comment: I'm agree with you. this is html 5. server recognizes device and based on type load the video. I'm sure it shouldn't be flash player as well.

Comment: Thanks Sparky, Yes you are right. I asked web developers to change the code from appAlias: {iphone:"iPhone",android:"Android",flash:"FlashApp"} to appAlias: {iphone:"iPhone",flash:"FlashApp", android:"Android}. Now it works fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the URL in your code and it seems, the page contains a flash video player. Maybe your phone/emulator doesn't have or support flash

Comment: Thanks Hans, but i think its html 5 player. Another reason is I have flash player installed in my device. when browser doesn't load the page therefore this player is shouldn't be flash player.

Answer (score 1):

this is a flash video, you need to enable the flash plugin:
   mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

Comment: thanks Rocel, however this method is deprecated from last release of Android 4.1 library. Do you know any other method like this?

Comment: yes indeed, This method has been deprecated in favor of setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState):
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setPluginsEnabled%28boolean%29

Answer (score 0):

Install flash player plugin for your device first from [here:](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.flashplayer), and then check with above code. by default your mobile browser uses google chrome-lite.

Comment: Thanks dear Zoombie, but i think its html 5 player. Another reason is I have flash player installed in my device. when browser doesn't load the page therefore this player shouldn't be flash player.